MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 object .send not working in IIS classic ASP
I have this code and it works fine on my local machine.  I moved it to our development server and when .Send is getting the error -2147483638 The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.  Any ideas what could be different on the servers to cause this?
  url = "https://auth.hstream.net/oauth2/token"
  data = "grant_type=client_credentials"


  Function PostTextFromUrl(url,authToken,data)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim oXMLHTTP
    Dim sHTTPResponse, sHTTPStatus  

    Set oXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 

    oXMLHTTP.SetProxy 1
    oXMLHTTP.SetTimeouts 600000, 600000, 600000, 600000

    oXMLHTTP.Open "POST", url, False
    oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", authToken 
    oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
    oXMLHTTP.Send data
  
    response.write (Err.Number)
    response.write (Err.description)
    
    response.write (oXMLHTTP.status)


    sHTTPStatus =  oXMLHTTP.status
    sHTTPResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText

    If Err.Number = 0 and sHTTPStatus = "200" and sHTTPResponse <> """{}""" Then
      PostTextFromUrl = sHTTPResponse
    Else
      PostTextFromUrl = HTTPErrorHandeler (HTTPStatus, HTTPResponse)
    End If
    On Error Goto 0

    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing

    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function

I would expect the send to work. It works fine on my local machine.

Is the bitness the same in both tests?

So I was able to catch the error but I don't know what it means. -2147483638   The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available

Have you tested with something like Postman from the Dev server to ensure that there isn't something like a Firewall in the way?

Have you tried using Postman, CURL or similar to test the response from the API? That will help determine if the issue is with the code or whether it is something API side.

Postman call works fine on the dev server.   Any other ideas?

I was able to get to the error.  -2147012851The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect
Then I was able to get that error resolved by adding the line:
oXMLHTTP.setOption 2, 13056 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763811(v=VS.85).aspx


Ignoring certificate errors is a terrible idea. Don't do it.
